# Kotlin: Generics in sealed classes

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to implement some kind of specification pattern with Kotlin and I have this code:

```
// T is the returning type for each query
sealed class Query<T> { 

  class ByName(val name: String): Query<List<User>>()

  class ById(val name: String): Query<User>()

}

class Repository {
 
  fun <T> find(query: Query<T>): T {
    return when(query) {
        is ByName -> getUsersByName(query.name) 
        // other query types
    }
  }

  private fun getUsersByName(name: String): List<User> { /*...*/ }

}
```

But I get an error:

```
Type mismatch
Expected: T 
Found: List<User>
```

If I cast the result to `T` (by adding `as T`), it compiles but I get `Unchecked cast` warning. Is it safe?

Is there a way to do this with no warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics doesn't get considered when considering sealed types. When the compiler analyses the `is ByName` branch for example, it doesn't go, "Ah I see `T == List<User>` here!".

When you cast to `T`, the compiler can't generate any code that checks whether the cast is valid at that point, because at runtime the type parameters all get erased, hence "unchecked cast".

From what I can see, the cast is always safe, because you checked the type beforehand.

One way to remove the warning is to inline the function and reify the type parameter:

```
inline fun <reified T> find(query: Query<T>) =
    when(query) {
        is Query.ByName -> getUsersByName(query.name) as T
        is Query.ById -> getUsersById(query.name) as T
    }
```

This would mean that `getUsersByName` and `getUsersById` can't be private anymore, but they can call other private methods.

This works because you are now replacing every call to `find` with that `when` expression (this is what "inline" means), and the caller always knows what `T` is (hence reified `T`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Very good explanation.